# My Appendices sections do not appear in the ToC, while the head Appendix does?

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

I want to have each of my appendices in the ToC, though it somehow only shows the Appendix. I am using `\usepackage{appendix}`

I want it to look like this:

```
Appendices
A Appendix 1
B Appendix 2
```

At the moment it looks like this

```
Appendices
```

Relevant code:

```
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\tableofcontents
\begin{appendix}
\appendixpage
\addappheadtotoc 
\include{Appendix}
\end{appendix}
```

My appendices are included in the Appendix.tex and are each a section. In the ToC all chapters and sections are included, so the tocdepth of 1 seems right to me?

Comment: That is not relevant code. We need a full minimal example we can copy and test as is. For example we do not know what you have in the `Appendix.tex` file (that include is probably not needed for this example). It might seem annoying to you that you have to do more work, but it makes helping you a lot easier for the rest of us, aka much faster answers for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the documentation of package `appendix` the marco `\addappheadtotoc` can not be followed by `\include`.

Use can use `\input{Appendix}`:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{Appendix.tex}
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{appendix}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\begin{appendix}
\appendixpage
\addappheadtotoc 
\input{Appendix}%<- changed
\end{appendix}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or you can put `\addappheadtotoc` within the included file:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{App.tex}
\addappheadtotoc% <- put it here
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{appendix}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\begin{appendix}
\appendixpage
\include{App}
\end{appendix}
\end{document}
```

The result is the same as above.

If the page number of the entry »Appendix« in ToC could/should be the number of the `\appendixpage` then you can use:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{Appendix.tex}
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{appendix}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\begin{appendix}
\cleardoublepage%<- added
\addappheadtotoc%<- before \appendixpage
\appendixpage
\include{Appendix}
\end{appendix}
\end{document}
```

[image]